# связь между java EE и java SE

Tags: java, spring, java-ee

Решил попробовать java EE и столкнулся с типичной проблемой "много инфы".

Теперь конкретнее. Нашел [вот такой замечательный сайт](http://www.spring-source.ru/docs_simple.php?type=manual&theme=docs_simple&docs_simple=chap01_p02) в котором идет описание того, как благодаря spring можно вывести "hello world".

Приближаясь к сути - зная java SE(опустим какие-то знания в андроиде, они как я понял никак не пригодятся), каким образом пройти эту пропасть между java SE и java EE. Ведь появление конфигов, мавен, самые разные спринги(защита, веб, мвс и тд) вводят в ступор.

Конкретно в приведенном выше сайте, с "hello world" я не понимаю в каком моменте связывается xml(учитывая синтаксис java EE) и обычную модель(класс) из java SE.

Теперь кратко: я не понимаю момент, в котором эти технологии переплетаются, на сайте просто как данность есть xml, и мне не понятно что куда втыкается. Подтолкните в нужном направлении?

Абстрактные объяснения вроде "есть bean, он идет от странички посылаемой сервером на единороге до станции 3\4 и там обрабатывается" будут не информативны. Прошу конкретики.

Comment: Да что там не понятно? Есть spring framework, и это его xml. Он его читает и на его основе создаёт все эти бины. Устанавливает связи между ними, пихая друг в друга. Используя spring, Вы составляете программу под spring framework. Ну а какая связь между SE и EE? Да пёс его знает. SE это база для всего что пишется на java? EE надстройка для своих целей, для EE.